# Loading data asynchronously in UICollectoinView inside UICollectoinviewCell

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, tvos

Hi I am using UICollectionView inside a UICollectionViewCell in swift tvOS so that it scrolls both horizontally and vertically.
Below is my Outer Collection view code.

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return variableCount
   }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Each section contains a single `CollectionViewContainerCell`.
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Dequeue a cell from the collection view.            
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CollectionViewContainerCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CollectionViewContainerCell
        {
            cell.configureWithData("some Parameters to build inner collectionView")
                print("Returning Cell")
                        return cell
        }

        return CollectionViewContainerCell()


    }
```

Method configureWithData is in CollectionViewContainerCell and in that I am calling an API asynchronously and reloading the inner collection view in dispatch_async.

Scrolling and displaying works fine. The problem comes with data when I scroll down outer collection view(4th cell which is not loaded initially) where in I get same data in 1st cell.  I can see that when I say dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier it re uses the memory allocated to the cell initially which is not visible now. but I am configuring the cell which is not reflecting here. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put some extra debug information to track down the data come back cycle for the remote API you are calling, in the case there is a delay in the inner collectionview datasource delegate methods and you have no provide additional clean up calls in the prepareForReuse method [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse], the info loaded for the 1st cell will remain visible even if the inner collectionview has been reused for the 4th cell, before the new data managed to fill in via the async call.